# aMember + Wordpress + bbPress -> Show Content Under bbPress Username Depending On Amember Subscription

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bbpress, amember

So i have this problem for which i've been trying to find a solution for 3 days already.

I have the Amember membership plugin, Wordpress and bbPress installed on my site and they are all integrated to handle users and subscriptions.

What i'm trying to do is show different content under the username of every member in my bbPress forum, depending on their subscription in aMember.

Her's the code that currently shows the rank in bbPress (i use a plugin for ranks), under username:

```
<?php echo cp_module_ranks_getRank(bbp_get_reply_author_id()); ?>
```

So bbp_get_reply_author_id() is the string that get's the username.

Now in order to show different content based on the aMember subscription i think i need to use use bbp_get_reply_author_id() to get the bbpress username, then use aMember's API to get the subscription for every member, and somehow make them to show different content depending on aMember subscription.

Here's a code that i currently use on my site (for something else) to access the aMember API and show different content depending on subscription:

```
<?php if(am4Pluginsmanager::getAPI()->haveSubscriptions(array(1,2,3))) : ?>
```

This is so confusing and frustrating. If anyone has any idea how to accomplish this, i would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.